# How to select links from this table with JSOUP?

Tags: android, parsing, hyperlink, html-table, jsoup

I have a table like this:

```
    <table class=firstclass>
   <tr>
      <td><a href....></a></td>
   </tr>
    <tr>
       <td><a href....></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><a href....></a></td>
    </tr>
```

I have other tables in this page, so I suppose that I have to use something like:

```
  doc.select("td.firstclass > a[href]");
```

but it does not work.

I solved with this:

```
       Element table = doc.select("table.firstclass").first(); //gets a table with the class                 "first class"
        Elements links = table.select("a[href]");
        for (Element link : links) {

            String textlink= link.text();
             String urllink= link.attr("abs:href");
            ));  

        }
// ...
```

Comment: 'does not work' doesn't tell us anything. Tell us what you want to achieve and what isn't working

Comment: Tried to grab the table getElementByClass("firstclass") and then just go through all td elements with the according get command and grab the link objects?

Comment: simply return me 0 links.
If I don't specify any table it works

Comment: Are you trying to get the whole table?

Comment: I would like to select all links in that table (then I need text and url, but I know how to do this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using "td.firstclass" is implying that your TD will have the class "firstclass".. which is why you get 0 results

You should do something like..

```
Document doc = ....; //however you get your document

Element table = doc.select("table.firstclass").first(); //gets a table with the class "first class"
Elements links = table.select("a[href]");
```

And from there you can process your links however you want